# Оценка важности предикторов модели Random Forest regressor с помощью R

Tags: r

**Проблема**: испытываю сложности в поиске подходящей библиотеки для оценки важности предикторов модели (Random Forest regressor). На данный момент мне наиболее часто встречались varImp функция (caret package) и importance функция (randomForest package). Так же я встречала упоминания про SHAP в R. На сколько я понимаю, методы отличаются и имеют свои подводные камни.

**Вопрос**: Какой из них наиболее применим к регрессионным лесам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Boruta, а встроенные в случайный лес "важности", наоборот, не используйте: https://explained.ai/rf-importance/
У меня есть пример: http://biostat-r.blogspot.com/2018/03/boruta.html

Comment: Спасибо. А с чем связана рекомендация не использовать встроенные функции?

Comment: См. статью по ссылке https://explained.ai/rf-importance/.